# Working with Word.Application in Powershell terribly slow for certain user profiles

Tags: performance, powershell, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I am scripting a lot in Powershell and now want to modify some Microsoft Word documents. I've noticed that my script is working fast on some servers, and terribly slow on other servers. After further analysis it seems that working with a Word.Application COMObject for some user profiles is fast, but for some other user profiles at the same server it's terribly slow.

In the meanwhile I were able to recreate the problem with just a few lines of code - and basically each method or action seems to be affected.

Here's what I am doing:

- Open new document
- Add some text
- Wait 5 seconds
- Add some more text

Nothing special, no rocket science - but doing anything with word after the 5 seconds pause is almost impossible.

Here's my code:

```
$WordApp1 = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application 
$Word1 = $WordApp1.Documents.Add()
$WordApp1.Visible=$true
$selection=$WordApp1.Selection
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
(Measure-Command {$selection.TypeText("test")}).TotalMilliseconds
```

And the result is:

```
77.3065    
91.4125    
63.3547   
80.9694  
71.1408   
87.1482    
10491.071          <----- LOOK HOW LONG IT TOOK    
10329.0877        <----- LOOK HOW LONG IT TOOK
```

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

I already tried using Bookmarks, Find/Replace and MailMerge with the same strange behaviour. I did a "Repair installation" and reset the Word user settings without improvement.

The same code in VBA is working fine and fast, thus there must be a relationship to Powershell or the Word class. Word is 2010, Powershell 4.0, Server 2008R2. Happens at multiple servers but for certain user profiles only. Affected user profiles have local admin priviledges.

Maybe it's related to the Interop.class? Maybe a bug and I require a particular hotfix/patch?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Open XML SDK instead in case if you deal only with open XML documents only. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

The fact is that **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article in MSDN.